# Change a column in python data frame according to previous values of the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas python as following 
[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KVEc.jpg)

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>AGE</th> 
    <th>GENDER</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
    <th>CODE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1   66   M       1    1
1   66   M       2    1
1   66   M       3    1
2   20   F       1    0
2   20   F       2    0
2   20   F       3    0
2   20   F       4    0
3   18   F       1    1
3   18   F       2    1
3   18   F       3    1
3   18   F       4    1

and I need to change the last column according to following(wherever the 'CODE' column is 1 keep the last row of That ID as 1 and change the previous rows to zero)

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>AGE</th> 
    <th>GENDER</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
    <th>CODE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>66</td> 
    <td>M</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18</td> 
    <td>F</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how is it possible to do it using pandas?

after looking it up I found this line of code which removes the last row of each group
    dfnew = (df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1] if len(x)>1 else x))

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are only `0` and `1` values?

Comment: @jezrael yes it has only 0 and 1 values.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your answer it helped me a lot, 
another question, as you saw I have several rows for each ID, I need to split my dataset into training and test keeping all the same ID in the same set (e.g. ID No. 1 should be just in Train(Test) and so on).
Can you please help solving this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately now I am offline, on phone only, so better is post new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get index by filtering by `1` and remove dupes by `ID` by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
i = df[df['CODE'] == 1].drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='last').index
```

Set column to `0` first and then replace by `i`:

```
df['CODE'] = 0
df.loc[i, 'CODE'] = 1
```

Another solution is create boolean mask and convert it to `int`s:

```
m = (df['CODE'] == 1) & ~df['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')
print (m)
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
dtype: bool

df['CODE'] = m.astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
    ID  AGE GENDER  TIME  CODE
0    1   66      M     1     0
1    1   66      M     2     0
2    1   66      M     3     1
3    2   20      F     1     0
4    2   20      F     2     0
5    2   20      F     3     0
6    2   20      F     4     0
7    3   18      F     1     0
8    3   18      F     2     0
9    3   18      F     3     0
10   3   18      F     4     1
```